# Venafi Digicert certificate renewal issue using terraform

Tags: terraform, certificate, renewal, digicert

I am trying to renew the DigiCert certificate using Venafi provider through terraform within the expiration window. However terraform code does not show the plan to renew/create the certificate. The same code was used to renew the certificate previously.

Appreciate any insights into this issue.

terraform version: 0.14.4
venafi version: 0.16.1

```
provider "venafi" {
  alias        = "private"
  url          = "https://certs.xyz.net/vedsdk"
  access_token = var.venafi_access_token
  zone         = var.venafi_zone_private
}


terraform {
  required_providers {
    venafi = {
      source = "Venafi/venafi"
      version = "0.16.1"
    }
  }
  required_version = "0.14.4"
}

resource "venafi_certificate" "cert" {
  common_name       = var.common_name
  algorithm         = "RSA"
  rsa_bits          = "2048"
  san_dns           = var.san_dns
  expiration_window = 720
  key_password      = var.cert_password
}
```

tried changing the expiration window directly in state file and also in resource.